# How to navigate to menu from my Game

Tags: android

**I used the code from the following website to design my game**

http://www.edu4java.com/en/androidgame/androidgame.html

I created the game correctly a its running well . I want to add an menu to my game .From which i can start the game by pressing a start button which is placed in a xml page.

Now i want to return to my menu page when my game is running  so i used the following  code in my back button in my phone

```
 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
    
     GameActivity.this.finish();             
     Intent menu = new Intent(GamedaActivity.this,Menu.class);
     startActivity(menu);
    
 }  }
```

I use this code and the game stop and return to menu . but it is showing a force close .
I checked my logcat it showed

fatal error -13

Null Pointer exception  @ Gameview & GameloopThread

how to close the game and move to menu without an error

Answer (score 0):

Change the order to:

```
Intent menu = new Intent(GamedaActivity.this, Menu.class);
startActivity(menu);

//call finish last
GameActivity.this.finish();
```

Also, if Menu activity was shown before GamedaActivity (so you started GamedaActivity from Menu activity), there's no need to override onBackPressed, as the system will take you to the previous activity (Menu) automatically, closing the current activity (GamedaActivity).

Comment: Please post your code for Gameview,  GamedaActivity and gameloop, and more lines from logcat

Comment: 01-29 01:59:15.542: E/AndroidRuntime(406): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-14
01-29 01:59:15.542: E/AndroidRuntime(406): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-29 01:59:15.542: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at com.workplease.GameView.onDraw(GameView.java:173)
01-29 01:59:15.542: E/AndroidRuntime(406):  at com.workplease.GameLoopThread.run(GameLoopThread.java:31)

Comment: code for my game is just a copy of the tutorial from this website  http://www.edu4java.com/en/androidgame/androidgame.html

Comment: Have you not modified it?

Comment: What is in line 31 in GameLoopThread? What is in line 173 in GameView?  You have GamedaActivity and GameActivity, what is the difference?

Comment: gameview  173 line   canvas.drawBitmap(bm, 0, 0, null); and  gameloopthread 31 line  view.onDraw(c);